# How to get mean values of certain regions in each slice in 3d matrix using logical indexing MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix, vectorization

In Matlab,

If I have a 3d matrix as following, I want to know the mean of the regions that have values greater than 5 in each slice. How can I use logical index to do this, with no loops please?

I would like to end up with an array of 3 by 1, with each element indicating the mean of the regions in their corresponding slice.

`m3d = randi(10,[3,3,3])`

m3d(:,:,1) =

```
 7     7     8
 1     9     8
 9     7     6
```

m3d(:,:,2) =

```
10    10     5
 9     7     8
 5     3     3
```

m3d(:,:,3) =

```
 9     7     5
 4     1     9
 5     9     1
```

Getting index

```
3d_index = m3d > 5;
```

My final

```
result = mean(m3d(3d_index));
```

in which I dont want to have the mean of all regions

Comment: Why would you avoid loops? The could be quite handy for your problem, and they can be also fast.

Comment: Hi CST-Link 44, I have to put this in a while loop, and it is a 256*256*100 matrix I'm talking about. So I try to avoid loops. I think Divakar has a great solution to this. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach -

```
%// 3d mask of elements greater than 5
mask = m3d>5

%// Sum of all elements greater than 5 in each slice
sumvals = sum(reshape(m3d.*mask,[],size(m3d,3)))

%// Count of elements great than 5 in each slice
counts = sum(reshape(mask,[],size(m3d,3)))

%// Final output of mean values for the regions with >5 only
out = sumvals./counts
```

### Benchmarking

Here's some runtime tests to see where all the posted approaches stand. For the tests, we have taken a random 3D array of size `1500 x 1500 x 100` with values in the interval `[1,255]`. The benchmarking code is listed next -

```
m3d = randi(255,1500,1500,100); %// Input 3D array

%// Warm up tic/toc.
for k = 1:50000
    tic(); elapsed = toc();
end

disp('------------------------ With SUMMING and COUNTING ')
tic
%// .... Proposed approach in this solution
toc, clear out counts sumvals mask

disp('------------------------ With FOR-LOOP ')
tic
N   = size(m3d, 3);
out = zeros(N, 1);
for k = 1:size(m3d,3)
        val    = m3d(:,:,k);
        lix    = val>5;
        out(k) = mean(val(lix));
end;
toc, clear out lix val k N

disp('----------------------- With ACCUMARRAY')
tic
ind = m3d>5;
result = accumarray(ceil(find(ind)/size(m3d,1)/size(m3d,2)), m3d(ind), [], @mean);
toc, clear ind result

disp('----------------------- With NANMEAN')
tic
m3d(m3d<5) = NaN; %// Please note: This is a bad practice to change input
out = nanmean(nanmean(m3d,1),2);
toc
```

**Runtimes**

```
------------------------ With SUMMING and COUNTING 
Elapsed time is 0.904139 seconds.
------------------------ With FOR-LOOP 
Elapsed time is 2.321151 seconds.
----------------------- With ACCUMARRAY
Elapsed time is 4.350005 seconds.
----------------------- With NANMEAN
Elapsed time is 1.827613 seconds.
```

Comment: Just to clarify.. do all the solution give same result to you?

Comment: @SanthanSalai No, I didn't check that, I would leave the value correctness part to OP for checking if interested.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a mask array to do this as follows,

```
m3d = randi(10,[3,3,3]);

%Set values less than 5 to NaN
m3d(m3d<5) = NaN
nanmean(nanmean(m3d,1),2)
```

Comment: Good idea to use `nanmean`!

Comment: `nanmean` is a nice function to know :) Also you might use `squeeze` to make it similar to OP's desired output. Also you might not use `1`, `2` not in `nanmean` as they are default. Coming to the point Here you cant use **nested** `nanmean` as it's **misleading**. you might test them manually to know it. Or you might try to use it for a single slice as a whole. It only gives the correct results when all columns have same number of non-NaN values.

Comment: Minor note: `nanmean` requires the stats toolbox.  If you want to implement your own version of `nanmean`, simply count how many `NaN`s there are per row/column or dimension you're working in, set the `NaN` values to zero, then to perform the average, simply subtract out this number from the total number of elements in a dimension.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done very easily with [`accumarray`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html):

```
ind = m3d>5;
result = accumarray(ceil(find(ind)/size(m3d,1)/size(m3d,2)), m3d(ind), [], @mean);
```